# Rounding off general equation

Tags: ceiling-and-floor-functions

I would like to know if there is a way to express the "roundup" function of excel or "rounding off of a number to the nearest whole number" in an equation form. e.g. in excel: roundup $(2.13,0) = 3$, or just rounding off a number: $2.1 \Rightarrow 3$ or $32.9 \Rightarrow 33$.. etc.

I'm faced with a problem with an equation where only whole numbers should be involved to function correctly.

e.g. $\left(\frac{10}{3} - 1\right )$ is $(3.33 -1)$ but it should be $(4 - 1)$...

Thanks.

Comment: rounding off to the nearest whole number makes 2.1 -> 2 ?

Answer (score 1):

We use ceiling and floor functions, represented as brackets.  So $\lceil 2.3 \rceil=3$ and $\lfloor 2.3 \rfloor =2$  Many computer languages use integer divide for integer variables, so $10/3=3$

Comment: Thank you for your answer, But i'm wondering if its possible to express it mathematically without using notations or symbols, more of like y/x = z where z has been rounded off to the nearest whole number.

Comment: I understand your comment, but the usual way to do this is really by using ceiling and floor functions.

Comment: You need to explain better what you mean by " express it mathematically without using notations or symbols".  Most of what we express mathematically uses notation and/or symbols.  Even $x^2$ does.  We often see people who don't like floor, ceiling, functions that have cases, absolute values, etc.  I don't understand the aversion.  *Most functions are not continuous*.  There are complicated ways to do it, often using sums of trig functions, but why?